# Ubuntu 20.04 "Temporary failure in name resolution" - recently reinstalled

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, discord

I rent a vps from contabo for about half a year now, it worked fine until now, because it started producing "Temporary failure in name resolution" errors. I read that this is a DNS error, I tried `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 1.1.1.1` but the problems is still here.

Also yesterday I completely reinstalled the vps but it didn't work.

### `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search invalid
```

### `resolvectl` status:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS          
DefaultRoute setting: yes          
       LLMNR setting: yes          
MulticastDNS setting: no           
  DNSOverTLS setting: no           
      DNSSEC setting: no           
    DNSSEC supported: no           
  Current DNS Server: 213.136.95.11
         DNS Servers: 213.136.95.10
                      213.136.95.11
          DNS Domain: invalid
```

I have a discord bot and usually the problem is came up there.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: having the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to edit the DNS IP's in **/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml** for Contabo VPS with Ubuntu 17.10 and above.

/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: REDACTED
      addresses:
        - REDACTED
        #- REDACTED
      #gateway6: fe80::1
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: REDACTED
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        search: [ invalid ]
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 8.8.8.8
          #- 213.136.95.10
          #- 213.136.95.11
          #- 2a02:c207::1:53
          #- 2a02:c207::2:53
```

https://contabo.com/blog/configuring-additional-ip-addresses/